# "mysqld" root access denied

Tags: mysql

My root user has the following privileges:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR root@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bedrock`.* TO 'root'@'%'                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I try to execute the following command, I receive the following error message:

```
mysqladmin root -pSOMEPASSWORD
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Whilst I'm able to execute mysql command normally, I'm not able to do it to mysqld. What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: IIRC `root@'%'` is not the same as `root@'localhost'`, have you checked the permissions on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the improvement of the knowledge base:
The problem was in permissions and the command. It works when calling `bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql` rather `mysqladmin root -pSOMEPASSWORD`. Note that user `mysql` had already got permissions throught chown -R and chgrp -R.

Answer (score 2):

1. You may have a user in your database without a password.  [Start mysql in safe mode](http://24x7servermanagement.com/blog/?p=44) then check to ensure none of your users have empty password fields.  If you find one, either add a password or delete the user.
2. It may be that the password is incorrect and needs to be changed

Comment: In fact, it was a problem on permissions, as my own answer in this topic. Thanks for helping! (I've vote up!)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p password yourChosenPassword
Enter password:
```

and re-enter your same chosen password at the prompt, you will then be able to call mysqladmin from the command line:

```
$ mysqladmin -uroot -pyourChosenPassword [OPTIONS] command command....
```